# Reduce voltage before LDO

Tags: low-power, ldo, voltage

I am working on a remote gate opener setup. It will be powered via a 12v battery (12-13.5v) and charged via pwm solar charger at up to 14.5v. I would like to use the HT7333 LDO datasheet [here](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/HT73xx.pdf)

It has a max input voltage of 12v and I would like to avoid the magic smoke :)

I am looking for a way of reducing the voltage to a safe range so the LDO will work while not draining the 7 Ah battery much when on standby.

**Background:**
The small micro controler will sleep for 1000ms then wake, turn on radio and listen for a signal for a few ms then back to sleep so the bulk of the time the current will be < 20 uA however when awake and opening gates its CPU:10 mA + 2xrelays 70~150 mA.

**My thoughts so far:**

**LDO vs Switching Regulator** - LDO as its sleep current is only 4 uA most SR are in the mA range and will empty my battery in winter. Also I have long range radio and the switching of the regulator will cause issues or make my PCB design more complex.

**Use another LDO with voltage range i need** - There are many designed for greater voltages but nothing in that class comes close to 4 uA current while CPU sleeps in fact most are 2-3 mA.

**Use diodes to reduce voltage before the LDO** - This seems the most promising as they will only consume power as it is drawn and not much if anything when not. However from the datasheets I have looked at it appears voltage drops on diodes are not static and change significantly based on the current load, so keeping it in a safe range could be tricky and I don't want so many that I have to extend the PCB (could fit in 4)

So I thought I would ask smarter people than I :) thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Borderline XY problem. Don’t use HT7333 and choose an appropriate LDO for the application.

Comment: Yes Borderline,that is where I started but low quiescent current and high input voltage is rear it seems especially if you also need affordable. I was hoping someone knew how to reduce the voltage pre LDO

Comment: @AndrewT do my suggestions not match your need?

Comment: @BeB00 sorry no the LDO must have no more that 12v current rating is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 3.9 V zener diode. At the 4 uA quiescent current it may only drop about 3 V, but that's still safe for you. At high load (10 mA), it will be very close to 3.9 V.

A lower V zener won't give you as much margin; a higher voltage one will limit you as the battery discharges.

I presume the MCU doesn't (can't) directly drive the relays -- likely you use a transistor (e.g. 2N2222). The coil of the relay doesn't have to connect to the LDO -- it can be connected to the full input.

Comment: Interesting, think we are getting somewhere, Yes I am using transisters to drive the coils but they are all part of the 3.3v domain powered by the LDO so max current through it is <200ma

Comment: All my experience with Zener Diodes are in parallel where it dumps voltage above a value, how does it work in serious? work it produce a voltage drop at the zener rated value? and like in the forward direction will it still very based on the current? I have a 5v Zener at home is the expected result that if I apply 14.4v ~9.4 will go to the ldo?  Sorry this area is new to me

Comment: Proven on a bread board, although there is still variability like normal diodes the Zener in reverse bias is far more consistent and should work for what I need. Thanks @jp314

Answer (score 2):

This isn't meant to be a shopping site, but **AP7370** and **TPS7A25** should do what you want.

In very low duty cycle applications, it's common to use an LDO instead of a buck regulator. You can also use both in parallel, turning on the buck when you need more current.

See [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduaa4/tiduaa4.pdf?ts=1594248755506&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) for more info on LDO+buck

Comment: Very interesting concept, but not what I am trying to solve, the LDO can handle the full range of current required but even on sleep will explode becuase the input voltage is too high the suggestion above wont solve that unless I have missed somthing.

Comment: @AndrewT you said that the input max voltage is 14.5V, is that not correct?

Comment: yes +/- a few mv relying on a soso solar charing module

Comment: @AndrewT Both of my suggestions are rated up to 18Vin. They also have lower quiescent current than the HT7333

Comment: according to your linked PDF its 12v +_10%, the problem is reducing voltage before the LDO not engaging something because load is high

Comment: @AndrewT You need to read the beginning of the answer. The linked PDF refers to the second paragraph

Comment: I'd add that I built a 24v to 3v3 switcher with a tps560430 and that consumes<100uA quiescent, and will be more efficient with actual current draw... And the PCB space is basically the same as the lm1117 it replaced... OP really hasn't looked very hard...

Comment: @beB00 yes the first LDO looks like it covers it, it is however 10 times the price and I havw 1000 HT7333 in stock but if another solution isn't given then I will mark it as the answer. thanks

Comment: @AndrewT AP7370 is $0.10 in qty 1k, are you saying that the HT7333 is 1 cent?

Comment: ~ 2.5 cents for qty100 and free postage from China, works out much cheaper (I live in New Zealand so postage is expensive from most of the big component sites) will keep looking for a  cheap option because the specs for AP7370 look great!

Comment: @BeB00 I checked the data sheet at 15v 150mA it is right on the edge so too risky for this implementation. However given its good set of protection features I still intend to purchase some. thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AndrewT to which datasheet specification do you refer? Are you talking about AP7370? If so, why not use TPS7A25?

Comment: @AndrewT I would actually suggest that using an LDO to power the relays generally is a bad/unnecessary idea, due to the excessive heat it will generate (unless you only keep the relay on for a few 100ms) . The correct approach would be to power the relays alone with a (3.3V) buck converter, although it seems like you are very cost sensitive? How long do the relays turn on for?

Comment: @BeB00 about 20-30 seconds (Opening a gate) I have bought a number of cheap relay modules which use one power source in so did it the same way. I will stay with in recommended wattage of LDO, but thanks for the heads up I will test and see how it goes for 1-2mins if it gets too hot. Then I will need to do a rethink. Given I am driving 12v I wonder if I shouldn't use 12v relays, drive the relays off the 12v and need to think it through some.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Zener diode in series with the input could work, if you select one with large enough voltage drop at the rated 4 uA.

Or, change the LDO.